# Laravel (5.7) query builder adding (redundant) 'is not null' to query's SQL

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Using Laravel 5.7, it seems Eloquent Query builder is adding a (redundant?) is not null - why is this?

[image: Contact model]

[image: Test code]

Output - where opportunities.contact_id is not null seems to be unnecessary?
[image: Output]

Comment: can you add `Contact` model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php`:

```
/**
 * Set the base constraints on the relation query.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function addConstraints()
{
    if (static::$constraints) {
        $this->query->where($this->foreignKey, '=', $this->getParentKey());

        $this->query->whereNotNull($this->foreignKey);
    }
}
```

This was the bug fix:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/1e80162e9a3a4c42a0079bd9f34e785197a66c07